# What does the __grid_constant__ parameter qualifier do?

Tags: cuda, nvidia

Several weeks ago, NVIDIA's Stephen Jones gave a [GTC talk named "CUDA: New features and beyond"](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/on-demand/session/gtcspring22-s41486/), in which he presented an upcoming feature of CUDA in v11.7: A qualifier/decorator for kernel parameters named `__grid_constant__`. I didn't understand the explanation about what that's supposed to mean.

Specifically, how does a `__grid_constant__  int x` differ from a `int x` ? Aren't they both just read by threads from constant memory?

Comment: From a look at the slides it looks like this will avoid per-thread copies of the parameter, so I guess it saves some memory.

Comment: For easier lookup: It appears at ca 31:50 in the talk and can be found on slide 60.

Comment: If I understand it right, this is explicitly for structs etc for which the compiler might be conservative and allocate per-thread copies (which are probably not in constant memory?). I could imaging that it makes no difference for (`const`) `int`.

Comment: I assume the main benefit is for kernels where not every function call is inlined. Say you call a function with that parameter as a const reference. Then the compiler must be conservative and assume that you cast it to a mutable reference and change it inside the function. So it has to create a local copy. With that annotation, the compiler is free to assume that you do no such thing.

Comment: @paleonix: Maybe the importance of structs is, that if you only use one member of the struct, you won't use up registers for the entire struct?